# How to delete certain rows with fix date but variable time using SQL query?

Tags: sql, amazon-rds

I have a database for which I need to delete multiple rows for date 2020-07-21. I am using below query to delete the rows. The issue happening is the rows that has time stamp of "11:00:06" gets deleted using below query but "11:00:07" rows remain. How do I edit the query so that all rows for 2020-07-21 will get deleted including all the times.

```
DELETE FROM test_daily.test_daily WHERE data_extract_timestamp='2020-07-21 11:00:06'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use range condition:

```
DELETE FROM test_daily.test_daily 
WHERE data_extract_timestamp >='2020-07-21'
  AND data_extract_timestamp < '2020-07-22'
```

Comment: @LarsSkaug We cannot use BETWEEN as proposed because it is both side inclusive meaning that `'2020-07-22 00:00:00'` will be deleted as well